# Redirection in browser is different from python code

Tags: python, http, python-requests

I want to open a link from a website using Python, so here is the flow:

1. I open the main URL *(e.g. www.url1.com)*
2. I scrape the page and find the button, it has a redirection link *(www.url2.com)*
3. when I use this link in browser it redirects to *(www.url3.com)* then immediately goes to another (Required link) *(www.url4.com)*
4. When I try the same flow using Python requests, it only goes to *(www.url3.com)*
5. I tried using the `allow_redirects` argument without any success

Here is my code:

```
import requests

headers = {
    'User-Agent': '',
    'authority': '',
    'scheme': '',
    'accept': '',
    'x-requested-with': '',
    'cookie': '',
    'referer': 
    }


def download(req):      
    resp = requests.get(req, headers=headers, allow_redirects=True)
    print(resp.text)
```

I also tried to print history using this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20475712/8245035).

but it keeps redirecting me too *(url3)*

Comment: If url3 redirects the browser using a `refresh meta tag`, `requests` will not follow it even with `allow_redirects` enabeled as it does not parse the html. [How to follow meta refresh in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2318446/how-to-follow-meta-refreshes-in-python)

Answer (score 1):

It's quite difficult to give a full answer without having the actual URLs you are using. That being said I think the problem is due to the fact that you are not saving/keeping track of the cookies, for that I would recommend you using [`requests.session()`](https://2.python-requests.org/en/master/user/advanced/#session-objects) when sending requests as it keeps track of the cookies for you.

All in all, I would recommend trying the following code:

```
import requests

session = requests.session()

headers = {
    'User-Agent': '',
    'authority': '',
    'scheme': '',
    'accept': '',
    'x-requested-with': '',
    'cookie': '',
    'referer': 
    }


def download(req):
    global session
 
    resp = session.get(req, headers=headers, allow_redirects=True)
    print(resp.text)
```

*(PS: if you are **scraping** a website I would highly recommend you use a User-Agent in the headers instead of leaving it blank)*

Hope this helps

Comment: The referer might also change the behavior of url3

Comment: @wuerfelfreak indeed! It’s difficult to say without the actual urls/website.

Comment: @Fozoro thank you I tried sessions but no luck yet,
 All the headers here are filled.
if you want the actual urls: url3(which opens on button click) : https://www.egy.best/api?call=NaaapmDdapaqapVcaVUazFTqazzVVVazpVYpqpapjYapaqapVUwqjmVqVVKcVapqpapxgIapaqapmVDvEumzxghwBapqpapwDYpaqapeDYDwDukhqzapqpapmDwapaqapVccqVxpVupqpapKeLUmDxKupaqVcaVUVaqTaVzxaVVaU&auth=7445579426cd5bd4c63e7ae0b8a464f1

But in browser it redirect to another one, while in python request, the response in the html of url3 and no further redirections